# BlenderGIS: importing georeferenced .tif DEM into Blender

Tags: add-on

I am new to Blender, and I am just trying to put a Structure from Motion produced DEM .tif into blender, but keep getting this error:  struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes.  What do I need to do?

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\operators\io_import_georaster.py", line 445, in execute
    grid = GeoRaster(filePath, subBoxGeo=subBox, useGDAL=HAS_GDAL)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\georaster\georaster.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._fromTIFF()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\georaster\georaster.py", line 125, in _fromTIFF
    tif = Tyf.open(self.path)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\lib\Tyf\__init__.py", line 479, in open
    elif first in [0x4d4d, 0x4949]: obj = TiffFile(fileobj)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\lib\Tyf\__init__.py", line 310, in __init__
    next_ifd = from_buffer(i, fileobj, next_ifd, byteorder)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\lib\Tyf\__init__.py", line 99, in from_buffer
    _read_IFD(obj, fileobj, offset, byteorder)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\lib\Tyf\__init__.py", line 83, in _read_IFD
    else: tt.value = unpack(fmt, fileobj)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.91\scripts\addons\BlenderGIS-master\core\lib\Tyf\__init__.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    unpack = lambda fmt, fileobj: struct.unpack(fmt, fileobj.read(struct.calcsize(fmt)))
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Try contacting the developers of the BlenderGIS addon directly (https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues) I doubt you will find answers here to such specific question.

Comment: thank you. I will try that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an issue with a third party addon and should be reported to the addon author